# Force specific model to be drawn in "texture" mode

Tags: python, 3d-view, draw-mode

I am using a 3D model that I mapped a texture onto as a reference image. (I find this workflow easier than using background images.) However, I cannot switch into wireframe mode and see the images at the same time, since the render mode is changed for all objects at once, meaning I will be constantly switching between wireframe and texture modes (with Z and alt+Z) to take a look at the reference image.

---

Long story short, I want an object to be rendered in texture mode, regardless of the current display mode for other objects. Is there a built-in way of doing that? I'm also open to solutions involving Python scripting.

Comment: You might want to try using an [image empty](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/empties.html#properties) instead

Comment: Thanks, that works. I would still like to have an actual mesh that behaves like that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use a workaround: instead of changing the general view mode i leave it as "textured" and change into wireframe the object I'm working on. Hope it helps.

[image]